# Why can't compilers insert code to detect buffer overflows?

Tags: c

Why don't C compilers have an option ( I said an option, there will be cases where you don't want to do this ) to transform code like this:

```
char a1[8];

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  char a2[16];
  char *p = (char *)malloc( 24 );
  int argv1_len = strlen( argv[1] );
  memcpy( a1, argv[1], argv1_len );
  memcpy( a2, argv[1], argv1_len );
  memcpy( p, argv[1], argv1_len );
  return 0;
}
```

into this:

```
char a1[8];
addAddr( a1, sizeof( a1 ) ); // build database of addresses and their lengths

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  char a2[16];
  addAddr( a2, sizeof( a2 ) );
  char *p = (char *)malloc( 24 );
  int argv1_len = strlen( argv[1] );
  addAddr( p, 24 );
  ptrCheck( a1, argv1_len ); // exit if argv1_len > size of a1
  memcpy( a1, argv[1], argv1_len );
  ptrCheck( a2, argv1_len );
  memcpy( a2, argv[1], argv1_len );
  ptrCheck( p, argv1_len );
  memcpy( p, argv[1], argv1_len );
  ptrCheck( p+5, argv1_len );
  memcpy( p+5, argv[1], argv1_len );
  return 0;
}
```

Doesn't the C compiler have enough information about the memory layout of locals and globals that it could build up a database of memory locations, either at compile time or put in code during run time, and their lengths and on any calls to strcpy, memcpy, memset, etc. or even code that does an assignment like *ch1 = *ch2; it could check the memory and make sure it is in bounds?  I assume there will be cases that this won't catch and that there will be a performance penalty that could be dealt with by turning this feature on or off completely or perhaps even by line or section of code and recompiling.  This is kind of like valgrind but better and with the compiler's help instead of just relying on the binary and only checking the heap.

Or even make the checkPtr API available to the developer so I could write my own strcpy:

```
char *mystrcpy( char *dst, const char *src )
{
  if ( checkPtr( dst, strlen( src ) ) )
  { /* do something custom */ }
  return strcpy( dst, src );
}
```

Comment: Pssst: [AddressSanitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Comment: Psst: a more complete list of techniques with various trade-offs, most of them implemented in most compilers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection

Comment: The best such tools are proprietary and either trade secrets or cost a lot. Nonetheless, static analysis can't ever do better than catch some cases. Catching them all is an undecidable problem (no program can every do it perfectly). Runtime checking of C is complicated, a university research topic, e.g. https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/Publications/BoundsCheckingForC.pdf .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is rhetorical/hypothetical **and** is based on a false premise.

Comment: Why is this rhetorical/hypothetical?  This is a simplified version of what happens in real programs.  What false premise is it based on?

Comment: So I took the code above, compiled it on gcc 4.8.2 on ubuntu with gcc main.c -fsanitize=address and ran it with ./a.out 123456789012345.  This should cause an error on the first memcpy: memcpy( a1, argv[1], argv1_len ); but nothing.  I even added a line:  if ( argv1_len > sizeof( a1 ) )
  {
    printf("a1 buffer overflow\n");
  } that is similar to the code that I am proposing would be produced and that does catch it and print out the warning about buffer overflow.

Comment: Did the same with clang-3.5 -fsanitize=address and it also doesn't report any buffer overflow.

Comment: @user3642186 **EDIT** Can you try with `./a.out 12345678901234567`? As it were you entered exactly 15 characters, which isn't an overflow of the 16 characters in `a2`.

Comment: yes, ./a.out 12345678901234567 , catches the second memcpy but it should catch the first one.

Comment: one thing to notice..  C does not perform runtime checking of much of anything.  (use ADA with its size and execution time penalties if you want those capabilities) .   It is the responsibility of the programmer to anticipate all such undefined behaviour events and properly/defensively code so they do not happen.   Caveats that greatly help when programming: 1) "never trust any data that is not hardcoded in the program.  2) never trust the user 3) never trust data sourced from outside the program.

Comment: in general, the compiler does not know much of anything about memory layouts, etc.  Normally the compiler just makes a object file that a linker can put together into an actual memory layout.  And the linker is not concerted about bad programming.

Answer (score 2):

Relatively new versions of compilers have options to enable such checking to some extend.

For example, [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) is the documentation for clang's address sanitizer.

You can enable them by compiling with `-fsanitize=address` (gcc and clang).

Clang (and I believe newer versions of gcc too) also includes sanitizers for undefined behavior (`-fsanitize=undefined`), uninitialized read (`-fsanitize=memory`) and data races (`-fsanitize=thread`).

Answer (score 2):

In the embedded world, compilers and tool chains commonly exist with options to perform various non-standard checks: NULL pointer dereferences, buffer overflows, etc. As you might guess, these features are computationally expensive (negatively impacting timing and performance), induce bloat, add to compile time, among other potentially unwanted effects. For these reasons, I've seen these "safe" compilation options enabled only during development/debugging (much like one would apply a static source code checker). I've rarely see released code ship with this stuff enabled.

Since I've mentioned static source code analyzers, I recommend taking a look at Coverity, Code Sonar, and others. In my experience, these tools do a much better job at detecting unsafe code than the usual compiler equipped with such checkers.